# Check starts-with for each element in array

Tags: java, arrays, string, startswith

Is there any utility function in java which does `String.startsWith` for each element in string array?

For eg:

```
String[] s = {"ABC", "BBV", "ABCD", "NBHH"};
```

Is there any way to do :

```
array.startsWith("AB");
```

Returns `ABC` and `ABCD`

Comment: lol.  I see you're trying to enforce the python numpy vectorize everything ideology upon Java.  Your choices are to roll your own for loop and iterate every element or try to use one of Java8's mapreduce like features.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the stream API:

```
String[] result = 
      Arrays.stream(s)
            .filter(a -> a.startsWith("AB"))
            .toArray(String[]::new);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Java 8, you can use filter like this :

```
String[] result = Stream.of(s).filter(a -> a.startsWith("AB")).toArray(String[]::new);
```

If you want to return a List you can use :

```
List<String> rst = Stream.of(s).filter(a->a.startsWith("AB")).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Stream` if you're using `Java 8`. In case you aren't then you'd probably want to use the solution below:

```
String s[]={"ABC","BBV","ABCD","NBHH"};

for (String i : s) {
    if (i.startsWith("AB")) { // startsWith() returns boolean
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```